# ios xcode header search path meaning

Tags: ios, xcode, search, path

I have to reference some library in my project and noticed that I dont understand the file path used in xcode

so for the `Header Search Paths`

I have for example

```
../**
```

so what the `**` means?

and in this case

```
./../** where is the path pointing to?
```

what is the relation with the unix file directory system?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means recursive. If you checked the box, next to the path (when you were filling it in), it will recursively look underneath that folder for files.

Comment: ../ is up one directory. ../../ is up two directories.